# php fwrite() fill's 0x00 in my text file

Tags: php, null, character, fwrite

I'm using the following code to write into a php file.

Problem is after the actual contents there are number 00's filled the text file; which I can in the HexEditor and in the end a 0x0A which I know is for \n.

```
    $val = "My Real Contents\n"; 
    $fileName = "./logs/" . date("m-Y") . ".csv";
    $handle = fopen($fileName, "a");
    fwrite($handle,$val);
    fclose($handle);
```

The output file is like in Hex -

```
    00000000   4D 79 20 52 65 61 6C 20  43 6F 6E 74 65 6E 74 73   My Real Contents
    00000010   00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0A   ................
```

I wonder if any one have any idea what's going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically nothing is going wrong.

The newline character (\n) that you print in your $val variable is equivalent to the ASCII character in hex 0A. If you remove that new line char in your $val string you won't get that second line.

Comment: I understand what 0x0A stands for. I'm concerned about a lot of 00 00 in my output.